# Can TLS enable end-to-end security between 2 users(not server) in IPv6?

Tags: tls, end-to-end-encryption

I'm studying iot Secure knowledge.
I find that people say that TLS/DTLS can provid e2e security but in HTTP diagram it will stop at Server.
A->Server->B and data at Server will be decrypted.
In my opinion TLS in web use this diagram because TLS usually need a Fix ip point(Usually Server), in IPv4 environment client often use NAT to make virtual ip for user.
If a iot device in 6Lowpan environment and being a client and Server is a user's personal device in IPv6 environment.Could just implement enduser-to-enduser TLS encryption?

I am sorry. I am not good at English.

Comment: See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165949/can-tls-be-used-in-p2p-encryption

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085335/is-webrtc-traffic-over-turn-end-to-end-encrypted for some interesting reading on how two peers can communicate with end-to-end encryption via TLS through a TURN server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. IPv4 vs. v6 is irrelevant, actually; the question is just "can TLS secure communication between two peers" and the answer is yes.

However, you might want to use something other than the standard public key infrastructure and X.509 certificates to authenticate the nodes. You *can* use certificates, for both client and server authentication, but with your own network-specific public key infrastructure. You'd need to create your own private certificate authority (CA), set its certificate as a trusted CA on every device, and use it to issue unique certificates to each device (assuming it's important to distinguish them). Each device's certificate will contain some identity, which the device might use local DNS to map to an IP address (alternatively, the certificates could contain the IP address directly, but make sure the verification code will allow this). Each device can initiate a connection as the "client" to any other node, verify the "server"'s certificate using the expected name (which again, might just be the IP address) and making sure the certificate is validly issued by your CA, and send its own certificate as a "client certificate" for mutual authentication (the "server" verifies the "client"'s certificate the same way, against the private certificate authority's key). Now each side knows who the other is; once authentication is complete, they will be able to perform authorization if needed, and will have an end-to-end secure channel for communication.

Alternatively, there are TLS authentication methods that are not based on certificates, and might be more practical for IoT devices. One option is [TLS-SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-SRP), which uses a "password" (doesn't have to be human-memorable) to authenticate both peers to each other. The password is exchanged before the secure connection is established, via the Secure Remote Password protocol, which handles both mutual authentication and key exchange. Relative to certificates, this is arguably simpler (and avoids some risks such as certificate expiration), but it also might not scale as well.

With certificates, each device only needs to remember two certificates (its own and the certificate authority's) and one private key (its own); it can authenticate any other node simply by verifying the certificate and extracting the identity (subject common name, etc.) from it. With SRP, each node (device) needs to store a mapping between identities and password verifiers (sort of like password hashes) for every unique identity out there. This means that if every node is going to have a unique identity, each other node needs to know its password verifier already. Also, you can't easily add new (unique) nodes to the network; you'd need to update every existing node so they know who the newcomer is. This *can* be done, especially for smallish networks (e.g. smart devices in a home), but it's quite possibly easier to go with certificates.

On the other hand, if you don't need cryptographic proof of unique identity - if it's ok if e.g. all devices of a given model are cryptographically indistinguishable, and report their specific identity in a less-provable way - then SRP becomes a lot simpler, as each device only needs to store the list of cryptographically unique identities. Makes adding new classes of device trickier, though (requiring updating all existing ones that they might communicate with).

Comment: Building a CA is really hard for an internal network? TLS-SRP should be on the top.

Comment: @kelalaka Not really? Tons of companies and products use them. Fundamentally, a CA is just a key pair with a self-signed certificate (marked valid for signing other certificates) and its certificate included in the trusted root CAs store for all of the relevant hosts. Then you use it to sign a cert for each device, and give the device the corresponding private key as well. If you can give each host its own password for SRP, you can give each host a cert and key about as easily... and you *don't* have to update every other host when you introduce a new one.

Comment: While reading your post, I got the feeling that it is hard to do. That is why asked. The SRP, however, should be easier for two nodes.

Comment: Yep, like I said, SRP doesn't *scale* well; too much hassle distributing the password verifier to each host. It's perfectly viable for small, rarely-modified networks though, and for very small ones (certainly for only two hosts) it's definitely simpler than a private CA.

Answer (score 0):

TLS is designed to work in a client-server configuration. You can see [here a description of the protocol](https://tls.ulfheim.net/). The client must start the connection to a server. However, "client" and "server" are just roles. In an architecture in your control and design, you can distribute certificates so that any client can act as a server in order to allow other clients to connect to it.

However, TLS was not designed for this. It's not easy to design such a system properly while ensuring the security of the communications. Indeed, you must be sure that each server has its own unique certificate, and that every client is able to verify the authenticity of those certificates.